# mysql multiple join with same table and grouping by category

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to that query

last news with grouping category (category limit 5) and order by published_at. Anyone help me?

Tables

news

```
 1. id
 2. caption
 3. published_at
```

category

```
 1. id
 2. name
```

news_has_category

```
 1. news_id
 2. category_id
```

sample output

```
caption01..  2016-01-28   category_id = 4

caption02..  2016-01-27   category_id = 4

caption03..  2016-01-26   category_id = 4

caption04..  2016-01-25   category_id = 4

caption05..  2016-01-24   category_id = 4

caption06..  2016-01-28   category_id = 3

caption07..  2016-01-27   category_id = 3

caption08..  2016-01-26   category_id = 3

caption09..  2016-01-25   category_id = 3

caption10..  2016-01-24   category_id = 3

caption11..  2016-01-28   category_id = 6

caption12..  2016-01-27   category_id = 6

caption13..  2016-01-26   category_id = 6

caption14..  2016-01-25   category_id = 6

caption15..  2016-01-24   category_id = 6
```

Comment: You would be better off adding a `category` column to the `news` table and setting up a foreign key between `news.category` and `category.id`

Comment: I can't change the table structures. becouse this script runing on alotof servers and on mobile applications.

And a news row might has multiple category. 

That's why i am using that structure.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating the tables in mysql as per your table structure. 
First you need to group by category and then by date in the grouped category is what I understand.

```
select caption , published_at,category_id from news,news_has_cat where id = news_id order by category_id desc,published_at;
```

The above query gives a output reverse ordered by category and date in ascending order in my case. So I had to do the below query as to meet to your requirement.

```
select caption , published_at,category_id from news,news_has_cat where id = news_id order by category_id desc,published_at desc;
```

Try it out

Comment: this solution for ordering by category_id.. but i want to that grouping by category with limit.. 
like that 

i have variable in my code categoryIdArray(5,2,6)

news1 - date - cat = 5
news2 - date - cat = 5

news3 - date - cat = 2
news4 - date - cat = 2

news5 - date - cat = 6
news6 - date - cat = 6

.... Thanks for answer